# Удалить из текста фрагмент от слова до первой запятой после него

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть строка, она получается при выгрузки из базы.

```
Вращающиеся печи № 4,5, ШГП-1,2, тракт выдачи извести из печей ШГП1,2 Источник № 6,Вращающаяся печь №4 1 ступень, Вход 1
```

Как  удалить символ и цифру(цифры) `№ 6`
Что бы получилось:

```
Вращающиеся печи № 4,5, ШГП-1,2, тракт выдачи извести из печей ШГП1,2 Источник,Вращающаяся печь №4 1 ступень, Вход 1
```

Ломаю голову над екселем.

Comment: Функция ПОДСТАВИТЬ().

Comment: Если всегда "№ 6", смотри комментарий @Akina. Если бывает и другое, покажите несколько разных вариантов, решение может отличаться. В заголовке - *и все, что после*, но в примере то, что после, осталось. Уточните и это.

Comment: @vikttur Судя по примеру, под "всё, что после" разумелось "всё, что после, до первого пробела". Что же до *всегда "№ 6"* - символ `№` в строке не единственный... правда, тот, в который тыкнуто пальцем, отличается тем, что после него НЕ пробел.

Comment: Да непонятно... После № есть пробел, хотя это неправильно, после запятой нет пробела... А *№ 6* - подразумевалось ПОЛНОЕ СООТВЕТСТВИЕ (три указанных символа). Но тут вопрос - если бы и печь была *№ 6* - что тогда? Без автора можно только гадать

Comment: Нужно убрать все символы, которые есть или будут до первой запятой. например Источник № 6, убираем № 6, если бы было Источник № 666, убираем № 666 то есть до запятой.

Comment: @vikttur нужно убрать Источник № 6, до запятой

Comment: Да Вы определитесь... Все символы до первой запятой - это ВСЕ, что находится слева. Первая запятая находится на 21 позиции, в начале текста.  Нужно убрать номер? Но в одном случае номер у Вас написан с пробелом после символа *№* (*№ 6*), дальше по строке - *печь №4* - здесь *№4* (здесь без пробела). Почему убрать именно этот номер? Вас просили показать на примере нескольких тектов. И с желаемым результатом. А пока здача непонятна. Будет толковый пример - будет и решение.

Comment: @vikttur вот есть запись, Вращающиеся печи № 4,5, ШГП-1,2, тракт выдачи извести из печей ШГП1,2 Источник № 6,Вращающаяся печь №4 1 ступень, Вход 1 Вопрос, как из этой записи убрать Источник № 6(может быть Источник № 666) слово источник будет всегда, далее пробел, знак номера, пробел и цифры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормального примера не дождались... Опираясь на показанное:

```
=ЗАМЕНИТЬ(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2)+9;ПОИСК(",";A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2))-ПОИСК("Источник";A2)-9;)
```

или

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2)+8)&ПСТР(ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2)+9;999);ПОИСК(",";ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2)+9;999));999)
```

Формулы убирают из текста фрагмент после первого слова "Источник" и до первой запятой после этого слова.

Убираем и слово "Источник":

```
=ЗАМЕНИТЬ(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2);ПОИСК(",";A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2))-ПОИСК("Источник";A2);)

=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2)-1)&ПСТР(ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2)+9;999);ПОИСК(",";ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК("Источник";A2)+9;999));999)
```

Comment: Спасибо. только запятую надо оставить. она нужна.

Comment: Запятую оставил

Comment: Спасибо , и слово источник тоже можно убрать?

Comment: а так все сработало

Comment: Убрали и слово...